# ruby/ indexed hash/ empty nils

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Having the following indexed hash :

```
{
  '1' => { a: :b },
  '2' => { c: :d },
  '3' => nil,
  '4' => { e: :f }
}
```

I'd be looking into "resetting" the indexed keys while removing the empty ones; in other words to produce the following :

```
{
  '1' => { a: :b },
  '2' => { c: :d },
  '3' => { e: :f }
}
```

What would be the best approach to get such result ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use an array instead of a hash? It seems like you're just interested in the order or elements.

Comment: BTW, `1:` is invalid syntax, you probably want `1 =>`

Comment: @Stefan edited. The thing is, I don't have the choice. I'm forced to use such structure, and I need to remove a key, while preserving some kind of order, without 'holes' in the sequence

Comment: Your numeric keys are strings?

Comment: @Stefan they are yep

Comment: Those are stored in a jsonb column, as excerpted here : `{"1": {}, "2": {}, "3": ...standard json payload..., "4": {}, etc...}`

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Multiple things, then I chose to see if anyone had a good solution here on SO

Comment: @Ben what I mean is: if the actual keys don't matter, you could put the values into an array and iterate it later on via `with_index` when you need a continuous sequence.

Comment: @Stefan I kind of tried that one; asking here to see if there was a more elegant/adapted solution

Comment: You must have been trying something else if it was not elegant ;-) Show your own attempts next time, please. It's much more helpful to improve existing code rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: hee I got the the point where I got lost in my own numerous tries; needed to clear the path (:! thx a lot for your helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just filter values and the assign new keys.

```
hash.
  values.
  reject(&:nil?). # or `compact`, credits to @KimmoLehto
  map.
  with_index(1) { |v, i| [i.to_s, v] }.
  to_h
#⇒ {"1"=>{:a=>:b}, "2"=>{:c=>:d}, "3"=>{:e=>:f}}
```

Please also refer to a valuable comment by @Stefan for a more concise 2.5+ version using `Hash#transform_keys`.

Comment: `reject(&:nil?)` can be replaced with `compact`

Comment: 2.5 version: `hash.compact.transform_keys.with_index(1) { |_, i| i.to_s }`

Comment: thx all a lot! Just to make sure; `.with_index(1)` means the index start at 1 instead of 0, right ?

Comment: @Ben last time I checked the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index), yes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). `reduce` starts with an empty hash (`reduce({})`) as initial value for `acc` in this case. Then it iterates through the `hash` and calls the given block for each key-value pair (in `el` as an [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html) [key, value]). The last value of each block will be the `acc` of the next iteration.

If the value of a key-value pair in `hash` is a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html), then I increase the number of keys in `acc` by 1 to get the next key and put it into acc with the value. So I complete the result in `acc` with each iteration.

```
hash.reduce({}){ |acc, el| 
  acc.merge(el.last.is_a?(Hash) ? {(acc.keys.count + 1).to_s => el.last} : {})
}
# => {"1"=>{:a=>:b}, "2"=>{:c=>:d}, "3"=>{:e=>:f}}
```

More explanatory:

```
hash.reduce({}) do |acc, el| 
  hash_to_merge_into_acc = {}

  if el.last.is_a?(Hash)
    new_key = (acc.keys.count + 1).to_s
    hash_to_merge_into_acc[new_key] = el.last
  end

  acc.merge(hash_to_merge_into_acc)
end
# => {"1"=>{:a=>:b}, "2"=>{:c=>:d}, "3"=>{:e=>:f}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h = { '1' => { a: :b }, '2' => { c: :d }, '3' => nil, '4' => { e: :f } }

s = '0'
h.each_with_object({}) { |(_,v),g| g[s = s.succ] = v unless v.nil? }
  #=> {"1"=>{:a=>:b}, "2"=>{:c=>:d}, "3"=>{:e=>:f}}.
```

See [String#succ](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-succ) (aka `String#next`).

Comment: Such terse. the network wants me to tell you to add some text so that poor hapless readers like me can understand that terseness. kthxbai

Comment: @Félix, `s = '0'`, `s = s.succ #=> '1'`,  `s = s.succ #=> '2'`, etc. `g` is an initially-empty hash, `v` are the values of `h`, so we have `g['1'] = { a: :b } unless  { a: :b }.nil?` (so `'1' => { a: :b }` is added to `h`),  `g['2'] = { c: :d } unless  { c: :d }.nil?` (so `'2' => {c: :d }` is added to `h`), `g['3'] = nil unless  nil.nil?` (so `'3' => nil` is *not* added to `h`), etc. The block variable for the hash key is an underscore (a valid local variable) to signify that it is not used in the block calculation. Please tell me if anything remains unclear.